# Запуск DialogFragment с помощью OnListItemClick?

Tags: android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Есть вот такой класс, в котором описан кастомный `ListView`. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы по нажатию каждого элемента из списка, выводился отдельный `DialogFragment`. (First.class = DialogFragment)

Этот способ крашит приложение при нажатии на любой пункт из списка:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
switch(position){
        case 0:
            i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), First.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Полный код класса:

```
    package ua.nikoz47.mobilewaiter.Tabs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import ua.nikoz47.mobilewaiter.Food.First;
import ua.nikoz47.mobilewaiter.R;

public class Menu extends ListFragment{

    Intent i;

    String[] menu_list={
            "Перші страви",
            "Другі страви",
            "Десерти",
            "Алкогольні напої",
            "Безалкогольні напої"};

    int[] menu_icons={
            R.drawable.first,
            R.drawable.second,
            R.drawable.dessert,
            R.drawable.alcohol,
            R.drawable.soft_drinks};

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<menu_list.length;i++)
        {
            map=new HashMap<>();
            map.put("MenuItem", menu_list[i]);
            map.put("MenuImage", Integer.toString(menu_icons[i]));

            data.add(map);
        }

        String[] from={"MenuItem","MenuImage"};
        int[] to={R.id.menu_textView,R.id.menu_imageView};

        adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.custom_menu, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    switch(position){
            case 0:
                i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), First.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Код First.class (Dialog Fragment)

```
package ua.nikoz47.mobilewaiter.Food;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import ua.nikoz47.mobilewaiter.R;

public class First extends DialogFragment {

    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    String[] first_list={
            "Борщ",
            "Борщ Зелений",
            "Грибний суп",
            "Солянка"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_first, null);

        getDialog().setTitle("Перші страви");

        lv=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sv=(SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, first_list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        sv.setQueryHint("Пошук страви...");
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String txt) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String txt) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(txt);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: По клику вы вызываете активити, а никакой не `DialogFragment`, а в вопросе спрашиваете про него. Вопрос в том, как вместо активити выводить диалог?

Comment: Прошу прощения за неверную формулировку, я новичок в андроид девелопменте, вопрос в том, как по клику вывести диалог, верно, First.class в моем коде это Dialog Fragment, я использовал getActivity() но для вывода диалога нужна другая команда?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы вызываете Фрагмент, как Активити. Фрагменты вызываются по другому, через `FragmentManager`. Метод `getActivity()` возвращает ссылку на активити, к которой прикреплен Фрагмент (в данном случае используется в качестве контекста) - он не выводит никаких диалогов и вообще ничего.

Comment: Понял, видимо нужно читать философию джавы... можете пожалуйста написать ответом код, как правильно заменить мой код тут: public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){ на нужный для вызова диалога, буду очень признателен!!, не знаю как это сделать...

Comment: Хотя читать философию ява конечно нужно, в данном случае она вам ни чем не поможет, так как это классы и методы фреймворка Android, а не Java/ Могу посоветовать читать Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2015г. Как вызвать фрагмент написано, в том числе и здесь, тысячу раз и тут даже поиск есть, а ресурс специально для того, чтобы в случае проблем не ждать ответа, а сразу его получить, найдя нужный ответ с решением, но вы можете и обождать неопределенное время, конечно, когда кто то ответит, если никуда не торопитесь.  Именно мне с телефона неудобно писать код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD для показа `DialogFragment` (Ваш `First.class`) используйте:

```
First dFragment = new First();
dFragment.show(fragmentManager, "tag"));
```

---

Для запуска `Activity`:

```
 i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), First.class);
```

Замените на

```
 i = new Intent(getActivity(), First.class);
```

P.S. К тому же, у Вас не помешает проверка

```
if(i != null) {
    startActivity(i);
}
```

и это у вас никак не новый `DialogFragment`, а `Activity`

P.P.S. Ну и когда задаете подобный вопрос, не забывайте стэктрейс ошибки добавлять.

Comment: Прошу прощения за неправильную формулировку вопроса, поправил вроде, First.class = DialogFragment в моем коде, добавил этот код в первый пост, log: yadi.sk/i/-OUQ4kVgraJdE в коде я использовал getActivity(), а нужно что-то другое для вызова не активити, а диалога, я правильно понял?

Comment: @Nikoz47_4pda обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь большое! Благодаря сообщению выше, сделал:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
switch(position){
        case 0:
            p.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), First.class.getName());
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

удалил:

```
startActivity(i);
```

Все заработало

Comment: Вместо ресурсоемкого вызова `First.class.getName()` вы можете просто указать любое строковое значение (например "first"), которое будет тегом (уникальным идентификатором) для вашего фрагмента в `FragmentManager` - по нему вы сможете обратиться к этому фрагменту через менеджер. Это будет гораздо "легче" для системы.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам, полезная информация для меня.